# What are the steps to upgrade jqGrid 3.5 to 3.6

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid

I'm using jgGrid 3.5 in my ASP.NET application. I would like to upgrade it to the new 3.6.
Is it enough just to replace the jqGrid JS file? Or are there any other changes I need to make in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that 3.6 has been officially released the upgrade is easy - just drop the files from the js and css directories into your application. Of course you should then re-test your app to make sure nothing was changed/broken, just in case...

Answer (score 0):

I just replaced, dev files from latest:
http://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commits/jqgrid36

be aware of file: jquery.jqGrid.js which loads modules.
besides, jQgrid uses jQuery 1.3.2 + jQuery UI 1.7.2

Comment: With jqGrid 3.5 you could download a single JS file which contained all of your selected modules in one file. Is there a way to do this yet with jqGrid 3.6?

Comment: I think not, until 3.6 is dev version.
Download latest build from: http://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/archives/jqgrid36